# Talking cat in Rick and Morty

Tags: analysis, rick-and-morty

[Rick and Morty](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2861424/) is a very creative and philosophical show. They always put some cultural references or philosophical debate as a central theme in their episodes.

I was watching its Season 4 Episode 4 '*Claw and Hoarder: Special Ricktim's Morty*' where two stories are playing in the background. One with the dragon and a second one with a talking cat. I understood the philosophical and cultural references in the dragon story but couldn't understand the talking cat one. Can someone tell me what the talking cat was in reference to?

Comment: The talking cat was the joke of a plot B story for Jerry. It was an alien that did some horrible thing and it just wanted to avoid it. It was also kinda an asshole. But more curiously, I didn‘t understand the dragon stuff at all and assumed it was an inside joke. Care to explain slut dragons? (Beside obvious slut shaming, or is that what you understood?)

Comment: @morbo Yes. Slut dragon was one of the aspect. My interpretation was that Morty wanted something unrealistic (dragon) while Rick didn't care. But unintentionally, Rick got bonded with dragon instead Morty. I think it can refer to unrealistic hopes we have for various things in our lives. (But I don't know what creator actually wanted. Was it some philosophical thing or utter artistic imagination who knows )

Comment: [The Cat From Outer Space (1978)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SEaSW1jtnQ)